# How to convert a char array of lines of numbers including '↵' to integers in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, character

I have variable 'txt' of the type char and I want to turn it into an array of integers:

> > txt =
> > '-1 1 -3 -1↵
> > -7 -4 -2 -3 -1 -2↵
> > -2 -24 -3 -1 -2 -2 -1 -1↵
> > -3 -1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5↵
> > -5 -2 -1 -1 -2 -11-15-27↵
> > -5 -7 -30-19-16-18-19-18↵
> > -5 -4 -28-28-19-13↵
> > -4 -3 -13 -6

```
 '
```

> > size(txt)

ans =

```
 1   160
```

> > num2str(txt)

ans =

```
'-1 1 -3 -1
 -7 -4 -2 -3 -1 -2
 -2 -24 -3 -1 -2 -2 -1 -1
 -3 -1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
 -5 -2 -1 -1 -2 -11-15-27
 -5 -7 -30-19-16-18-19-18
 -5 -4 -28-28-19-13
 -4 -3 -13 -6
 
 '
```

> > str2num(txt)

ans =

```
 []
```

double(txt) also return an array of numbers but they are not the same as the number in the txt array.
How can I turn txt array into integers?

Comment: What exactly is the rule by which we should make this string into an array? Do you want the array `[-1 1 -3 -1 -7...]`?

Comment: Whatever it is that you're trying to do, it should be possible using the [regexp command](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).

Comment: The size of your "rows" is not uniform, i.e. 4 then 6 then 8 elements, how do you expect this to be handled? Matrices in MATLAB must have all elements within a "rectangle" defined

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes exactly I want them to be a 1 by n number array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find and eliminte the 'newline' charachters in your code first. the ASCII code for the newline is 10. So, try to use this code to find, eliminate them and replace them with space.

```
arr= #read the text;
arr(double(arr)==10) = ' ';
a = find(arr=='-')-1;
a = a(a>0);
indcs = a(find(arr(a) ~= ' '));
for i=1:length(indcs)
    arr = [arr(1:indcs(i)), ' ', arr(indcs(i)+1:end)];
    indcs = indcs+1;
end

x = str2num(arr)
```

Comment: Yes that's great you saved my life:D